# android- handling the screen orientation a bit differently

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a UI which when the device is rotated, the icons get rotated.
Normally, when a device is rotated the `onXXX` lifecycle methods get called, and I'd like to avoid this when the screen orientation changes and would like to rotate the icons on the main UI instead. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: First: lock your layout in one position. Portrait or landscape. Second: Place icons according orientation.

Comment: @blackapps , the second part of your comment is exactly what I was asking in my question